# I want to send a value with http.get() of angular 4.0

Tags: angular

I want to include a value in the URL.
I want to send with such URL.

```
http://localhost:4200/get.html?start=2016&end=2017
```

It is a method I made.

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
dateData = {start:"2016",end:"2017"};
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, body: dateData});
this.http.request(new Request({
  method: "Get",
  url: "./get.html"
}),options).subscribe((res: Response) => {
  console.log(res);
},error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

But,Value not included

```
http://localhost:4200/get.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `URLSearchParams`, not `body`

You can try this:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('start', '2016');
params.set('end', '2017');

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: params);
```

Comment: This comment was displayed on webstorm.　"TS2345:Argument of type '{ headers: headers; params: params;}'is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'params' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'."　　Corrected this"{ headers: headers, search: params}" Errors are gone.
But i can not send it.

Comment: Params is written in this document. Why would it be an error?
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html#!#params-anchor

Comment: Is `params` existed when you view code of `RequestOptions` class?

Comment: Beside that, your method is `get`, so you should use `this.http.get` better than `this.http.request`

Comment: "this.http.get("./ajax.php", options) "Succeeded with this making method.

Answer (score 0):

In the way that you are doing it, your not using `http.get()` correctly. you should use it like so.

```
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
let startDate = '2016';
let endDate = '2017';
let baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/get.html';

this.http.get(`${baseUrl}?start=${startDate}&end=${endDate}`, {headers:headers})
.subscribe((res: Response) => {
  console.log(res);
},error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: This making method has no versatility.Every time I make http.get() I have to make it.In the case of http.post(), json can be passed.Is it impossible for http.get()?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean. `get` is for reading data, `post` is for creating new data.